# How to squash merged commits into one?

Tags: git

I have a git history like this:

```
master branch:

* 0001: lastest commit
* 0002: commit1
* 0003: commit2
* 0004: Merge commit
 \
  * 1001: aa
  * 1002: bb
  * 1003: cc
 /
* 0005: commit3
* 0006: commit4
* 0007: Merge commit
* \
  * 2001: aa
  * 2002: bb
  * 2003: cc
 /
* 
....
```

I want to squash 1001~1003 into one commit, and 2001~2003 into one commit, and other merge commits into one commit

I tried `git rebase first-commit` and try to squash 1001~1003, etc, it's very hard and never successes.

Is there some command like `git squash master 1001..1003`, which means squash 1001 to 1003 into one commit in master branch?

Comment: all merges are already done in your case, so you can only re-write the whole history ether using rebase or cherry-picking some commits. As you already discovered, it is could be hard. Next time you merge, use `merge --squash`.

Comment: Yeah, I should have used `merge --squash`...